# Using dataclasses.MISSING as optional parameter value with a Python dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to make the `set` parameter optional but still allow `None` to be a valid value. Based on [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field), it suggested that `dataclasses.MISSING` could be used a default value to assist in this.

> As shown above, the `MISSING` value is a sentinel object used to detect
> if some parameters are provided by the user. This sentinel is used
> because `None` is a valid value for some parameters with a distinct
> meaning. No code should directly use the `MISSING` value.

But by using this as follows:

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Var:
    get: list
    set: list = dataclasses.MISSING

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.set is dataclasses.MISSING:
            self.set = self.get

 print(Var(get=['Title']))
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
print(Var(get=['Title']))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'set'
```

Comment: Can you use something like this? ```set: list = field(default_factory = lambda:[])```

Comment: ```name:str = field(default_factory = lambda: list(give_name())[0])``` I use this to retrieve a random name for each instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can use `dataclasses.MISSING` in this way, so I would simply use a dedicated `enum`.  Since it's an `enum`, it's gauranteed to be identical only with itself, so it should give use what you want:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

_field_status = Enum("FieldStatus", "UNSET")

@dataclass
class Var:
    get: list
    set: list = _field_status.UNSET

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.set is _field_status.UNSET:
            self.set = self.get

print(Var(get = [7]))

print(Var(get=[7], set=[8]))
print(Var(get=[7], set=None))
```

Obviously this prevents the user from setting `set` to `_field_status.UNSET`, but presumably they don't need to do that.

Note that I am slightly confused as to why `None` is a valid value for something which is hinted as a *list*, but the principle stands.

Answer (score 7):

> **No code should directly use the MISSING value.**

This part above is noted in the docs for a reason. Therefore, we should avoid use of the `MISSING` usage (and import) in our application code if possible. In this case, using `MISSING` is not at all applicable to our use case.

Assumed usage (by avoiding directly working with the `MISSING` sentinel value, and instead using `dataclasses.field(...)`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Var:
    get: list[str]
    set: Optional[list[str]] = field(default=None)


print(Var(get=['Title']))
# Var(get=['Title'], set=None)
```

##### But where is `MISSING` actually used?

The `MISSING` is a sentinel object that the `dataclasses` module uses behind the scenes, for its magic.

You can inspect the source code for `dataclasses.field` and find a clear usage of it there:

```py
def field(*, default=MISSING, default_factory=MISSING, init=True, repr=True,
          hash=None, compare=True, metadata=None):
```

You'll see the declared default value for fields such as `default` is `default=MISSING` instead of `default=None`. This is done mainly to identify if the user actually passes in a value for `default` or `default_factory` to the factory function `fields`. For example, it's perfectly valid to pass `field(default=None)` as we did in example above; however, since the default value is actually `MISSING` instead, `dataclasses` is able to detect that a value has been passed for this parameter (a value of `None`).

##### How `MISSING` is declared

If you inspect the source code of the `dataclasses` module, or by `Ctrl` (`Command` on Mac) + left clicking on the keyword `MISSING` anywhere in code, you can see how `MISSING` is actually declared:

```py
# A sentinel object to detect if a parameter is supplied or not.  Use
# a class to give it a better repr.
class _MISSING_TYPE:
    pass
MISSING = _MISSING_TYPE()
```

##### A Potential Solution

Piggy-backing off how the `dataclasses` module defines `MISSING`, you *could* theoretically define your own (empty) class, and then instantiate the class.

I, however, feel that class instantiation could be obviated in this scenario. Here's a one-liner to create a sentinel class / type:

```py
class _UNSET: ...  # here the ellipsis (`...`) is essentially the same as `pass`
```

Usage, then, would be as follows:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass


class _UNSET: ...


@dataclass
class Var:
    get: list
    set: list | None = _UNSET

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.set is _UNSET:
            self.set = self.get


print(Var(get=[7]))
print(Var(get=[7], set=[8]))
print(Var(get=[7], set=None))
```

This correctly distinguishes between scenarios when `set` is omitted in the constructor, or when a value for `set` is specified, such as `set=None`.

The result, is also as expected:

```py
Var(get=[7], set=[7])
Var(get=[7], set=[8])
Var(get=[7], set=None)
```

Comment: How do you detect if a value is MISSING? I mean, how do you determine if the dataclass was created `Var(get='Title')` instead of `Var(get='Title', set=None)`?

Comment: @UselesssCat Good question. I added updates to my answer above. See the newly added sections on "How `MISSING` is declared" and "A Potential Solution".